# How should I manage correctly images provided by JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to parse all the Image provided by downloaded JSON on my App. So, I've heard many ways to do that correctly. Which API should I used to manage the Images on my App? How should I do that, can I have an example?

I also wanted to take care correctly of delays between:

***Run the app --> Load data --> Populate UI elements***

What should I do to minimize this delay, I think a professional app shouldn't take that long to load all components.

***That's the part where I'll populate a UITableView with Images.***

```
var arrCerveja = [Cerveja]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //TableView DataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrCerveja.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID") as! TableViewCell

        let model = arrCerveja[indexPath.row]

            cell.labelName.text = model.name
            cell.labelDetail.text = "\(model.abv)"
            cell. imageViewCell.image = ???? //How should I do that? 
        return cell
    }
    //TableView Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getApiData { (cerveja) in
           arrCerveja = cerveja
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

***Model Folder:***

```
import Foundation
struct Cerveja:Decodable{
    let name:String
    let abv:Double
    let image_url:String
}
```

***Networking Folder:***

```
import Alamofire


func getApiData(completion: @escaping ([Cerveja]) -> ()){
    guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
        print("URL Error")
        return
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data == response.data{
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: response.data!)

                completion(decoder)
            }catch{
        print(error)
            }
        }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to cache the downloaded images, many libraries exist to help you do that, here is a list of some of them:

- [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
- [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift)
- [Cache](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache)

Kingfisher is a good one that also allow you to download the images and explain you how to use the library with table views.
Caching the images will also reduce the loading time the next time the app is open.
You can also use [this library](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView/) to display a user friendly loading to the user during loading.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me man! How about AlamofireImage and SDWebImage are they good as well?

Comment: No problem, I have never used AlamofireImage or SDWebImage so I don't want to  give my opinions on them but it seems that AlamofireImage will help you downloading images but not caching them (so no performance improvements during the next launch). SDWebImage seems very similar to Kingfisher and also very powerful. It should do the job to simplify for you the downloading and caching of images. I can only suggest you to make a little more research on both and select the one that fit better your project.